# How to check DBNull into linq or int32?

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to fetch all the rows where `CategoryId` is `null` . I write the following code but it gives me error

> " Operator ' == ' can not applied to operands of type 'int?' and
>   System.DBNull

```
   public Nullable<Int32>  CategoryId { get; set; }
    Game objGame;
    var query = (from gametypebygametype in db.GameByGameTypes.Where(x => x.CategoryId == DBNull.Value)
                  join game in db.Games
                 on gametypebygametype.GameId equals game.GameId into joined
    from game in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select new
                                 {
                                     game.GameId,
                                     game.GameName
                                 }
                                ).Distinct();
                    List<Game> objlistGame = new List<Game>();
                    foreach (var item_temp in query)
                    {
                        objGame = new Game();
                        objGame.GameId = item_temp.GameId;
                        objGame.GameName = item_temp.GameName;
                        objlistGame.Add(objGame);
                    }
```

Comment: Maybe you need `x.CategoryId.HasValue == false`

Comment: It's not the LINQ part you're having issues with, it's the `Nullable<Integer>`

Answer (score 2):

Try just using `null` rather than `DBNull.Value`, or `HasValue = false`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your `WHERE` clause and use [`Nullable<T>.HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx)  as:

```
.Where(x => !x.CategoryId.HasValue)
```

from

```
.Where(x => x.CategoryId == DBNull.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch all the rows where `CategoryId` is `null`, then simply check if nullable has value assigned:

```
db.GameByGameTypes.Where(x => !x.CategoryId.HasValue)
```